# Connecting on wordpress woocommerce Klarma through Stripe

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, stripe-payments

I would like to know if there is a plugin or how it is possible to connect Klarma (already active on my stripe) in a wordpress store managed with woocommerce.
As I can see there are 2 wordpress plugin for Klarma but they are not connected with Stripe.
Anybody experienced the same problem?
Thanks

Comment: WooCommerce is a commercial product with a skilful support team. So is Stripe. Questions about configuring it are off-topic both here and on https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ , but the support team will help you.

Comment: support didnt answer back, stripe say i need to ask to woocommerce and woocommerce said i need to ask to stripe.....